# A cast of ObjectifyImpl to Ofy compiles, but fails at runtime in Eclipse/Java8

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, objectify

The cast in the title works fine in Objectify 5.0.3 (compiles, runs locally in Eclipse, and runs deployed on GAE).  When trying to upgrade to Objectify 5.2.22 (along with other upgrades, details below), the compiler does not object to the cast, but at runtime in Eclipse, I get this message in a popup:

```
com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ObjectifyImpl cannot be 
cast to com.strongbrain.db.Ofy
```

The Ofy/ObjectifyService/OfyFactory-related code is unchanged from 5.0.3. (below)

Details:
I'm trying to upgrade a free site ( http://strong-brain.com/ ) which has been running without attention for a couple of years on Google App Engine.  The major components, original versions, and new target versions are:

```
             Original     Target
appengine-api    1.9.25       1.0-sdk-1.9.71
GAE sdkbundle    1.9.25       Cloud SDK version 228.0.0
Eclipse          Luna         Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Java             1.7          1.8
Objectify        5.0.3        5.1.22
DWR              2.0.10       2.0.10
```

Thus far I'm only trying to run locally in Eclipse.  When I start a localhost server, the main index.jsp page displays fine, as do other pages statically linked from from index.jsp.  However, pressing any button invoking server processing (e.g. ‘Start’ on a task page) produces a popup with the message above.   Searching the code claims the only cast to (Ofy) is in file com.strongbrain.db.OfyService.java, shown below.

The relevant file com.strongbrain.db.Ofy.java, and the portion of web.xml relating to Objectify are also provided below.

File com.strongbrain.db.OfyService.java

```
package com.strongbrain.db;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

/**
 * Custom version of ObjectifyService which uses the custom Ofy and OfyFactory.
 * Sets up OfyFactory instead of the standard ObjectifyFactory.
 * Derived from Motomapia app.
 */
public class OfyService
{
    static {
        ObjectifyService.setFactory(new OfyFactory());
    }

    /**
     * @return Ofy extension to Objectify
     */
    public static Ofy ofy() {
        return (Ofy)ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }

    /**
     * @return OfyFactory extension to ObjectifyFactory
     */
    public static OfyFactory factory() {
        return (OfyFactory)ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

File com.strongbrain.db.Ofy.java

```
package com.strongbrain.db;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull;
import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.Nullable;

import com.googlecode.objectify.Key;
import com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ObjectifyImpl;

/**
 * Basic data access interface wrapper. Extends the basic Objectify interface to add convenience methods.
 * Derived from Motomapia app.
 *  @see <a href="https://github.com/stickfigure/motomapia/blob/master/java/com/motomapia/Ofy.java">Motomapia Ofy.java</a> 
 */
public class Ofy extends ObjectifyImpl<Ofy>
{

    public Ofy(OfyFactory base) {
        super(base);
    }

     /** More wrappers, fun */
    @Override
    public OfyLoader load() {
            return new OfyLoader(this);
    }   

    /* Convenience methods using the OBT DBMgr naming scheme, but made generic. */

    public <T> Key<T> insertEntity(T e) {
        return updateEntity(e);
    }
    public <T> Key<T> updateEntity(T e)
    {
        return save().entity(e).now();
    }
    public @NonNull <T> T retrieveEntityByKey(Key<T> k)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("null")
        @NonNull T e = load().key(k).safe();
        return e;
    }
    public @Nullable <T> T findEntityByKey(Key<T> k)
    {
        return load().key(k).now();
    }
    public <T> void deleteEntityByKey(Key<T> k)
    {
        delete().key(k).now();
    }
    public <T> void deleteEntity(T e)
    {
        delete().entity(e).now();
    }
    public <T> void deleteEntities(Iterable<?> entities)
    {
        delete().entity(entities).now();
    }
    public void deleteEntityKeys(Iterable<? extends Key<?>> keys)
    {
        delete().keys(keys).now();
    }
    public <T> Map<Key<T>, T> batchRetrieve(List<Key<T>> keys)
    {
        return load().keys(keys);
    }
}
```

web.xml fragment:

```
        <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

Expected: Data access via Objectify
Actual: Popup described above.

Comment: Does it work if you revert to Objectify 5.0.3?

Comment: Replaced Objectify 5.1.22 jar with 5.0.3 jar, and now get the following exception:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService
 at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:50)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to replace the stock `com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter`: this filter causes `ObjectifyService.begin()` to be called at the start of the request, which inn turn uses the `ObjectifyService`'s factory to create an `Objectify` instance.  This happens before your `OfyService` static initializer has a chance to set the `ObjectifyService`'s factory.

I think you need to provide your own filter that sets the factory first:

```
public class ObjectifyWebFilter extends ObjectifyFilter {
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,  FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    ObjectifyService.setFactory(new OfyFactory());

    super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
  }
}
```